# Visual Studio 2010: Import csproj into another csproj "injected" via svn-externals

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, svn, webforms

i am looking for a way to 'import' a .csproj file into another .csproj file.

For example the following scenario:

Main.csproj:

```
<Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
<Compile Include="Class2.cs" />
```

SubMain.csproj

```
<Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
<Compile Include="Class2.cs" />
<Compile Include="Class3.cs" />
```

Now it would be nice to somehow inherit from 'Main.csproj' in my 'SubMain.csproj'.

Maybe something like that in 'SubMain.csproj':

```
<Include File="Main.csproj" />
<Compile Include="Class3.cs" />
```

So it would automatically add the files that are in 'Main.csproj'?

Is something like that possible with Visual Studio 2010 for ASP.Net Web Projects?

And if not, are there any alternative solutions for the given scenario?

Thanks.

**EDIT Why do i need that:**

In my case both projects are ASP.Net Web Projects (WebForms). 
The 'Main.csproj' is the Basic Application. 
The 'SubMain.csproj' is a customer specific version of the Web Application. (Has the same functionality as the Basic Application + some extra features or some other behaviours for specific features)

Currently i do this by simply copy the Main.csproj and add my additonal files to it. But this method is not very nice and also causes problems when files are added to the Main.csproj and so they are not automatically in my 'SubMain.csproj'.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm with SLaks - it looks like you are about to work around the basic concept of referencing assemblies/libraries.

Comment: I updated the description and described the background why i need this.

Comment: The case you describe should be solved by a customer specific branch in your source code version control system. Any modern VCS will support this scenario. If you don't use a VCS yet, this is a good reason to start doing so.

Comment: @Filburt: We already use SVN. We have multiple SVN repos. One for the basic version and one for each customer. The basic version is added to the customers repo using svn externals. The problem i have are the csproj files. For the customer version i just copy the basic csproj and add the customer files to it. But this is a problem when the basic project file changes. Then i need to merge these for every customer...

Comment: @H0ff1 Okay, now the picture gets clearer. Did you explictily decide against branching? Branching would allow you to propagate changes from your basic version to your customer versions. You would however loose the "automatic" update svn externals provide and have to do explicit merges from basic to every single customer.

Comment: @Filburt: i still don't get how branching would help with my problem. The automatic update is something we need otherwise we would die in merge chaos as it is a really big and complex application with a lot of changes in basic and customer version.

Answer (score 4):

Likley better approach is to make "Main.csproj" a "class library" (assembly) and add it as reference to other project(s).

To achieve exactly what you asking for use [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) element to add shared files.

> By using the Import element, you can reuse code that is common to many project files. This makes it easier to maintain the code because any updates you make to the shared code get propagated to all the projects that import it.
>
> By convention, shared imported project files are saved as .targets files, but they are standard MSBuild project files. MSBuild does not prevent you from importing a project that has a different file name extension, but we recommend that you use the .targets extension for consistency.

```
<Import Project="mySharedFiles.targets"/>
```

Note that `Import` will have copies of classes built into each assembly - if you need to share classes between assemblies class library approach is the one to use.

Comment: I cannot change it to class library because it is a Web Project. I have added the background, why i want to do that in my description above.

Comment: @H0ff1: Are you familiar with the idea of virtual directories and applications? That may help you. If you truly need to "merge" customer-specifics into a base web application, then you have an interesting time ahead of you.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Does the <Import Project="" /> also work for asp.net webforms projects? And how can i generate a .targets file?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: How would virtual directories and/or applications would help me here?

Comment: You might have each customer have their own virtual directory/application.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: This is already the case. Every customer has his own system with a own  virtual application in IIS.

Comment: @H0ff1 - you can "Import" any MSBuild file (like .csproj). Since both of projects are webforms you'll need to see how merging would work (most likely you'll need seriously cleanup "main.csproj" file before it works ok).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Have you an example project where this works? I have tried to setup two new projects and tried to import the first one to the second one but the compiler complaints about that the files of the first project could not been found..

Comment: @H0ff1 no I don't have any sample to share. You need to get detailed build logs (use command line build with MSBuild) and see what it actually tries to load. Probably you need to make items in imported project to refer to files differently - not sure.